# How to append already generated XML string to XML generated with minidom?

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML string that I've already created from a dict:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from dict2xml import dict2xml


s = {
    'HierarchyNode': {
        'levelid': '2'
    }
}

xml = dict2xml(s)

print(xml)
```

**Output:**

```
<HierarchyNode>
  <levelid>2</levelid>
</HierarchyNode>
```

But I'm trying to add it into XML which has already been built (under the read element)

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from dict2xml import dict2xml


s = {
    'HierarchyNode': {
        'levelid': '2'
    }
}

xml = dict2xml(s)

print(xml)

doc = minidom.Document()

# request
request = doc.createElement('request')
doc.appendChild(request)

# read
read = doc.createElement('Read')
request.appendChild(read)

# inner payload
read.appendChild(xml)

pretty_xml_str = doc.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
print(pretty_xml_str)
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\working_dir\test.py", line 26, in <module>
    read.appendChild(xml)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 115, in appendChild
    if node.nodeType == self.DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'nodeType'
```

I can't append it as a text node because the text node strips the characters.

Comment: minidom is only generating XML at the moment you ask it toprettyxml the rest of the time it is represented as Python objects. The XML you want to insert is of str type while nodeType is expected by minidom. The error gives you a nice hint :-)

Comment: @Ivonet - appreciate you response. Not super helpful though, I guess I should've mentioned that I understand the AttributeError. The problem with building a node is that I'd need to know the element ahead of time. IE - there's a reason why there's no attribute 'nodeType' - it's because it doesn't exist. I did end up figuring it out however, see below.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered there's something called importNode. This allows the xml string being passed in through parseString to be copied to the dom.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
from dict2xml import dict2xml


s = {
    'HierarchyNode': {
        'levelid': '2'
    }
}

xml = dict2xml(s)

# print(xml)

doc = minidom.Document()

# request
request = doc.createElement('request')
doc.appendChild(request)

# read
read = doc.createElement('Read')
request.appendChild(read)

# inner payload being read in
payload = parseString(xml)

# import payload into doc, and append to read element
x = doc.importNode(payload.childNodes[0], deep=True)
read.appendChild(x)

pretty_xml_str = doc.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
print(pretty_xml_str)
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<request>
  <Read>
    <HierarchyNode>


      <levelid>2</levelid>


    </HierarchyNode>
  </Read>
</request>
```